# How to fix 'The data types datetime and uniqueidentifier are incompatible in the add operator.'

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

```
DECLARE @caseId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @fieldId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @columnName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @dateValue DATETIME,
    @tableName nvarchar(MAX);

set @command = 'update ' + @tableName + ' set ' + @columnName + ' = ' + @dateValue + ' where Id = ''' + @caseId + '''';
exec sp_executesql @command;
```

Getting error while running the update command. - The data types datetime and uniqueidentifier are incompatible in the add operator.
Can someone help?

Comment: Can we see the definition of your table and the values you are inserting into variables ?

Comment: You are updating the nvarchar column with datetime, try to convert the datetime variable with nvarchar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should use query parameters for the date and id values rather than mungling them in the query string.

That would look like:

```
declare 
    @pCaseId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @pFieldId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @pColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @pDateValue DATETIME,
    @pTableName nvarchar(MAX);

set @command = 'update ' + @pTableName + ' set ' + @pColumnName + ' = @dateValue where Id = @caseId';
exec sp_executesql 
    @command,
    N'@dateValue DATETIME, @caseId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER',
    @pDateValue, 
    @pCaseId
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @caseId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @fieldId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @columnName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @dateValue DATETIME,
    @tableName nvarchar(MAX);

set @command = 'update ' + @tableName + ' set ' + @columnName + ' = ' +convert(nvarchar(100),@dateValue,120) + ' where Id = ''' + @caseId + '''';
exec sp_executesql @command;
```